# Connection error while Connecting to MicroSoft Sql Server 2012 through Java Code

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to connect to Ms Sql server 2012 through following java code.

```
`public class MsSqlServerConnection {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    try {

        Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
    /*  String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Gpstrack;user=;password="; */
        Connection connection = null;
        /*Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");*/
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=BARCELONA\\V&V;database=Gpstrack");

        if(connection!=null){
            System.out.println("connection is successfull");
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("Connection error");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

}`

When I run the above code I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'BARCELONA\V&V'.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2529)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1905)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1045)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at MsSqlServerConnection.main(MsSqlServerConnection.java:17)
```

So please help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: Login failed sounds to me like your user/password are not correct

Comment: user name is :BARCELONA\V&V and there is no password.

Comment: You have escaped the backslash. Try escaping the `&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an active directory domain user with a blank password? That's fairly unusual and somewhat dangerous, but I'll just try to focus on your question.

'BARCELONA\' to sql server indicates a domain name, and I do not see your connection string indicating integrated security.

So it could be something as simple as indicating integrated security in your connection string: `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;`

See [this link for documentation on building your connection string url for jdbc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=SQL.110).aspx).

Comment: It's Working Thank You.